# /scan topic subscribed to costmap_2d [new user]

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, base-laser, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have (sensor_msgs/LaserScan) and I want it subscribed to costmap_2d. Apparantly costmap_2d doesnot explicitly subscribe to sensors [Reference](http://answers.ros.org/question/191283/laser-scan-to-occupancy-grid-using-costmap_2d-new-user/). By checking [API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/annotated.html) it seems Costmap2DROS is a ROS wrapper for a 2D Costmap. Handles subscribing to topics that provide observations about obstacles in either the form of PointCloud or LaserScan messages.

I am new in ROS. I think I have to give /scan topic as an input to Costmap2DROS. I think I should write a Publisher - Subscriber through this Tutorial: (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B) )
to be able to give a laser scan to Costmap2DROS. Am I right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191393//scan-topic-subscribed-to-costmap_2d-%5Bnew-user%5D/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are new to ROS, I would suggest working through all the beginner/intermediate tutorials to get a better idea about how ROS works. You do not need an intermediary publisher-subscriber, as your laserscan driver already *publishes* /scan, and costmap_2d will *subscribe* to /scan. The only reason to have a node in the middle would be to process the data in some way.

To get costmap_2d to subscribe to scan, you should read this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on 2014-08-27**:
Thanks Paul for being patient with me. I will study the package and share the result ...

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-27**:
ROS parameters are in yaml format - they can either be loaded in individually with  tags in roslaunch, or in a batch using [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps#CA-7d4716539be6148c30e65fd2a8ab6a7a1a5dce57_1) and a .yaml file.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-27**:
This is described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams#Using_rosparam). A minimal .yaml file for the costmap setup is shown in the tutorial (minimal.yaml). The 'dictionary' is the plugin array: plugin [] in yaml syntax.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-27**:
To have the costmap subscribe to the laserscan, you need to add an obstacle layer to the plugins, instead of a static layer (for a static map), or a voxel layer (for 3d maps).

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-27**:
Not a yaml file, but same idea embedded directly in a launch file. https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration/blob/hydro-devel/launch/global_map.launch